# no such column: dashboard_book.id django

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am trying to save data from a pandas DataFrame into the SQLite database on a django project but I keep getting the error "no such column: dashboard_book.id".

At the moment I have just a simple Excel file with one column "title" with a string inside. I want to import this into a DataFrame and then save it into Django model. It might seem a bit overkill but it is just the start as I want to build onto it with some automation scripts I have in place.

Simple model in models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Admin registration in admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title']
```

Then the attempt to save it into database using dataframe.to_sql() this call is in a separate file with other business logic:

```
data_table = pd.read_excel(setting.import_directory + "/book_table.xlsx")
data_table_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_table,)
engine = create_engine('sqlite://db.sqlite3')
data_table_dataframe.to_sql("dashboard_book", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

When trying to access the model on the admin panel the error is received and no data is being saved into the model.

When the model is first migrated, the table has an ID column and the title column in the database. However, after the attempt is made to load the table with the dataframe data, the ID column is gone.

I have tried all different parameters in the to_sql() call and checked the files to make sure I am not missing anything but I cant find where the issue is coming from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you open the Book table in a database browser, what columns does it have?

Comment: Just added it in question....When the model is first migrated (before any attempt to save the data from the dataframe), it has an ID column but it disappears when the to_sql() method is run. Do I need to explicitly add the ID in my data that I am trying to save? I thought Django managed that itself?

Comment: It looks like `to_sql()` is recreating the table from scratch (because of the `if_exists='replace'` argument) and it doesn't know about the `id` column.

Comment: Thats done it John! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As John advised in a comment - it was due to the `if_exists='replace'`. I changed this to the code below and it works.

```
data_table_dataframe.to_sql(name="dashboard_book", con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, index_label=None, method=None)
```